# Programatically set layout_width of EditText in Android

Tags: java, android, dynamic

So I have an application that dynamically adds a table row every time the "Add Row" button is pressed. The code attached is the code that runs when "Add Row" is pressed. What I am trying to do is have 3 EditTexts next to each other on the same row. In order to do that, I need to change the Layout_Width of each EditText so the first EditText doesn't cut the other two off the screen. I can't seem to figure out a way to properly do this and was wondering if anyone would help me out. After I figure out how to do that, the next step is to adjust the layout_width according to the screen size but thats later down the road. It needs to be done programmatically because a user can theoretically have as many rows as they want to.

```
private OnClickListener btnListener = new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {   

            tablerow = new TableRow(getActivity());

            ed1 = new EditText(getActivity());
            ed1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

            ed2 = new EditText(getActivity());
            ed2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

            ed3 = new EditText(getActivity());
            ed3.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

            tablerow.addView(ed1);
            tablerow.addView(ed2);
            tablerow.addView(ed3);
            table1.addView(tablerow);

        } 

    };
```

Comment: try ed1.getLayoutParams().width=32;

Comment: Every time I do this, it gives me  LA NullPointerException. I am assuming it is because the Edittext currently doesn't have a width for some reason?

Comment: You need to set layoutParams before. setting width.

Comment: Oh that might be why actually. Will report back in a few hours. Thanks!

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is LayoutParams and its "weight" value.

Try:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f);

ed1 = new EditText(getActivity());
ed1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
ed1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The third value (1.0f) in the LayoutParams constructor is a weight...all EditTexts in that TableRow should end up the same width.

Comment: You don't want to specify an exact width. MATCH_PARENT in the LayoutParams width value and the 1.0f weight will automatically adjust the EditText widths such that all three are the same size AND combined they fit the table width, which you have hopefully defined with a MATCH_PARENT width so it fits the screen width.

Comment: So this is on the right track but doesn't completely work. It does make every EditText appear on the screen but for some reason it gives ed1 90% of the screen and ed2/ed3 share the remaining 10%. My table does have a MATCH_PARENT width.

Comment: After playing with this, it was something to do with my layout in my XML file. Your solution worked like a charm. Thanks so much! I know it had something to do with LayoutParams but i couldn't figure out how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try next approach, it is based on xml. You will be able to play around with layout at `table_row.xml`.

```
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.a_mn_button_add_row:
                onClickButtonAddRow();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void onClickButtonAddRow() {
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.a_mn_table);
        tableLayout.addView(View.inflate(this, R.layout.table_row, null));
    }
}
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/a_mn_button_add_row"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Add row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/a_mn_table"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

*table_row.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</TableRow>
```

*table_row.xml* for use case with 3-1-2 proportions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</TableRow>
```

Comment: I was very excited to try this solution because I like how it is written. It wouldn't work for my application because "tableLayout.addView(View.inflate(this, R.layout.table_row, null));" in MainActivity provided an error. This is because I am extending Fragment insted of ActionBarActivity. The only way I could get the application to run is to call that line with "getActivity()" instead of "this" but then the application crashed because of a NullPointerException. Thanks for the help though! This looks elegant.

Comment: @JacobMoultonRhodes yes, you'll get crash because you need to adapt code for fragment usage